# How to implement simple audio loopback in QT

Tags: qt, audio-recording, qtmultimedia

I need to loopback audio recorded from the microphone straight to the speaker using QT (qt 5.7 on Windows...) - assume I **can't** use window's internal mic->speaker loopback (enable "listen to this device" on the microphone panel).

Any direction how to do that?

Comment: You could probably chain together these: `QAudioInput`, `QBuffer`, `QAudioOutput`. I'm doing a similar task this week (with sound modification in-between), so feel free to post the code. Or I post what I'll make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the discussion on https://forum.qt.io/topic/19960/qaudioinput-redirect-to-qaudiooutput/3

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioOutput>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    const auto decideAudioFormat = [](const QAudioDeviceInfo& devInfo)
    {
        QAudioFormat format;
        format.setSampleRate(8000);
        format.setChannelCount(1);
        format.setSampleSize(16);
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

        if (devInfo.isFormatSupported(format))
        {
            return format;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.\n";
            throw 0;
        }
    };

    QAudioInput audioInput(decideAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice()));
    QAudioOutput audioOutput(decideAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice()));

    audioOutput.start(audioInput.start());

    return app.exec();
}
```

### Adding a buffer in-between

> I've encountered this issue before. If I'm not mistaken, the read() and write() functions share the same pos() tracker. This is what happens:

```
QBuffer buffer;

buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite); // buffer.pos() == 0
buffer.write(someData, 5); // Writes in positions 0 -- 4, buffer.pos() == 5;
buffer.write(someData, 5); // Writes in positions 5 -- 9, buffer.pos() == 10;
buffer.read(otherBuffer.data(), 10); // Tries to read from position 10 onwards. No data found
```

> 2 solutions:
>
> Implement your own, separate read-position and write-position trackers. Then, call seek() in readData() and writeData() to set pos() -- point to the end of the data before writing, but point to the middle of the data before reading
>
> Use 2 separate buffers, and copy bytes from the input buffer into the output buffer

So, with separate buffers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QBuffer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QBuffer rdBuff;
    QBuffer wrBuff;
    wrBuff.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly);
    rdBuff.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

    QObject::connect(&wrBuff, &QIODevice::bytesWritten, [&wrBuff, &rdBuff](qint64)
    {
        // remove all data that was already read
        rdBuff.buffer().remove(0, rdBuff.pos());

        // set pointer to the beginning of the unread data
        const auto res = rdBuff.seek(0);
        assert(res);

        // write new data
        rdBuff.buffer().append(wrBuff.buffer());

        // remove all data that was already written
        wrBuff.buffer().clear();
        wrBuff.seek(0);
    });

    const auto decideAudioFormat = [](const QAudioDeviceInfo& devInfo)
    {
        QAudioFormat format;
        format.setSampleRate(8000);
        format.setChannelCount(1);
        format.setSampleSize(16);
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

        if (devInfo.isFormatSupported(format))
        {
            return format;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.\n";
            throw 0;
        }
    };

    QAudioInput audioInput(decideAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice()));
    QAudioOutput audioOutput(decideAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice()));

    audioInput.start(&wrBuff);
    audioOutput.start(&rdBuff);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Wow! What a great answer! Thanks a million :)